# How to remove the 'OK' button from QuickPick

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a VS-Code extension using Typescript.

In one of the flows, it creates a QuickPick menu using the following API:

```
let quickPick: vscode.QuickPick<vscode.QuickPickItem> = vscode.window.createQuickPick();
quickPick.items = this.getValues();
quickPick.canSelectMany = true; // Enable checkboxes

// Set listeners
quickPick.onDidChangeSelection(items => {
    // --> Do an important action here <--
});
quickPick.show();
```

When the user clicks on one of the checkboxes, the action occurs immediately -> There is no need for `OK` button in my scenario.
[image: Quick pick items]

Does somebody know how to remove the `OK` button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem that calling `quickPick.ok(false)` to hide the button would work.

But looking at [the code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/workbench/browser/parts/quickinput/quickInput.ts#L759) the `ok` button is always rendered for `canSelectMany` QuickPicks.

You could use `quickPick.customButton(true)` together with `quickPick.customLabel("your label")` to replace the `ok` button instead.

However when I look at your scenario maybe you do not need multi select if each click on a checkmark already performs the action. Checkmarks are usually used only to mark multiple things to happen, hence the OK button to run the combined actions.

Comment: Thanks, but 'ok', 'customButton' and 'customLabel' are not accessible in 'vscode.QuickPick'. Am I missing something here?

Comment: It was added as public method 7 months ago via this PR:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/47017a8ea97cf7ed269a65e0eb771af5ac26f542

Comment: It hadn't been added to 'https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/vscode/index.d.ts'. However, I accepted your answer since now I have a better understanding. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. I would have thought the type definitions are generated from the source and not manually. Maybe create an issue over there?

Comment: They have almost 3000 open issues. I'll consider to create a pull request.

Answer (score 2):

just add `quickPick.ok(false)` to hide your ok button.

You can also customize you ok button with `quickPick.customButton(true)` with `quickPick.customLabel("label")` to replace ok and ad it with ur custom ok button

Comment: Thanks, but if I'm not missing something, this API is not accessible in the vscode npm library.